# Protocol neutral URLS with wp_enqueue_script (SSL issues)?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, ssl

How do I use wp_enqueue_script so that I get protocol neutral URLs?  Here is how I'm currently using it:

`<?php wp_enqueue_script('name', get_bloginfo('template_directory'). '/js/name.pack.js'); ?>`

I saw that `home_url()` is protocol aware so I figured `theme_url()` would be also but I'm getting the error below when I use it.

`Call to undefined function theme_url()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't -- URLs must have a protocol for WordPress to enqueue them. What you can do, though, is detect which protocol to use and then use that.

```
$protocol = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http';
$url = "$protocol://example.com/resource";
```

But for enqueuing scripts from your theme, you should use [get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) or [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) which already handle SSL:

```
wp_enqueue_script('name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/name.pack.js');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also leave off the protocol, like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'be-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500' );
```